# Change Login to logout after users

Tags: php, mysql

hi guy i need some help bout this code..
how to change the log-in into logout after the user log in?
can please give a sample for this code? thanks in advance..

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" href="">Log-in</a>

<form form id="login" action="login.php" name="login" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()" align="center" role="form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
        </div>

        <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-primary"> 
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

here is the Php code
sorry i did not include it a while ago

```
//Include database connection details
require_once('connection.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$username = clean($_POST['username']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE uname='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['user_ID'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['fname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_MIDDLE_NAME'] = $member['mname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lname'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location:admin/index.php");
        exit();
    }
    else 
    {
        //Login failed
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
        $errflag = true;
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            header("location:index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

?>

Comment: How do you know that user is logged in?

Comment: Yeah...where is your php?

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated. Suggest using mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for one of the session variables you've previously assigned.

```
<?php if($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']){ ?>

    <form id="logout" action="logout.php" name="logout" method="POST" role="form">
        <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="logout" class="btn btn-primary"> 
    </form>

<?php }else{ ?>

    // your login form

<?php } ?>
```